# How do I enable auto-renew for my domain registration in Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I just switched my domain registration to Amazon Route 53. In the console, my domain is listed as "Auto Renew: Disabled".

How do I set my domain to auto-renew? There's no option to enable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the auto-renew feature is not available yet, see https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=560750

"Auto renew: We will be releasing this feature in the next few weeks." (Aug 3, 2014)